# window.location on the aliased domain

Tags: javascript, window.location

In the project I work with there is an apache aliasing set up so that the domain site-main.com points to the site-source.com (both our domians).
When configuring the js app I use window.location to determine where we are, and it returns not the site-main.com, but rather site-source.com.
However if I go to the browser and type window.location, it shows site-main.com.

What could be a reason for this behavior which looks really strange since both codes run in the browser?

Comment: What kind of aliasing is it? A real `VirtualHost`, or a header redirect?

Comment: Real VirtualHost according to what admin told me.

Comment: Hmm, then it shouldn't happen. Any chance of a live link?

Comment: Sure, please http://dev.instantcommunities.net/. On the top of the console you can see the result of console.log(window.location.host), which is the source domain, but not current.

Comment: Seems that your script is running in a `frame`, so you're getting the location of the frame's `window` object. Use `window.top.location.host` instead.

Comment: @patrick why not make that an answer, it solved the issue

Comment: Thanks @Pekka, but I wasn't sure if there were any potential browser issues, and was too lazy to test or investigate. OP has the resolution noted. :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patrick dw gave a right answer to the questions in comments :) The redirect was implemented in a wrong way in our server.